# grab value from checkboxes and post as list to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

Check the code bellow. I am doing post a list of `ProductId` to my controller and wanted to receive it with view model called- `UpdateProductStatus`. but the problem with my current code is: ajax post it to controller successfully but the `UpdateProductStatus` cant grab any value of `ProductId`. This always returns null. Whats wrong i am doing here? Possibly in ajax i am doing wrong i think. How can i fix this to receive all `ProductId` as a list form controller? Thanks in advance

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult UpdateProductStatus([FromBody]List<UpdateProductStatus> UpdateProductStatus)
        {



            return Json("ok");
        }
```

View Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BlexzWeb.ViewModels
{
    public class UpdateProductStatus
    {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Jquery:

```
 $('#btnActivate').on('click', function () {


            var allSelectedProductId = [];
            var allSelectedProductIdWithKey = [];
            $('.chkItems:checked').each(function() {
                allSelectedProductId.push($(this).val());
            });

            for (var _allSelectedProductId in allSelectedProductId) {
                allSelectedProductIdWithKey.push('ProductId'+':'+_allSelectedProductId);
            }

            console.log(allSelectedProductIdWithKey);



            //var things = JSON.stringify(allSelectedProductIdWithKey);
            var things = JSON.stringify({ 'UpdateProductStatus': allSelectedProductIdWithKey });


            console.log(things);

            $.ajax({
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Products/UpdateProductStatus',
                data: things,
                success: function () {
                    console.log('sssss');
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    console.log('fffff');
                }
            });
```

Html:

```
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="chkItems" value="1">
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="chkItems" value="2">
<button id="btnActivate">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code is sending a payload like below for the ajax call.

```
{"UpdateProductStatus":["ProductId:0","ProductId:1"]}
```

Your action method argument is a list of `UpdateProductStatus` objects. So for model binding to work properly with your current action method parameter signature, your payload should be like below.

```
[{"ProductId":"1"},{"ProductId":"2"}]
```

There is no need to specify the parameter name. Just pass an array of items, each with a `ProductId` property and it's value.

```
var allSelectedProductIdWithKey = [];
$('.chkItems:checked').each(function () {
    allSelectedProductIdWithKey.push({ ProductId: $(this).val() });
});

var things = JSON.stringify(allSelectedProductIdWithKey);

$.ajax({
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Products/AppendClientFilter',
    data: things,
    success: function (res) {
        console.log('Successs', res);
    },
    failure: function (response) {
        console.log('Error', response);
    }
});
```

You can also remove the `dataType` in ajax call. jQuery ajax will guess the proper type from the response header and in your case you are going to return explicitly JSON.

Answer (score 1):

To bind to your controller method, you need to send an array of objects containing a name/value pair for `ProductId`. To build your array of objects, use

```
$('#btnActivate').on('click', function () {
    var allSelectedProductId = [];
    $('.chkItems:checked').each(function() {
        allSelectedProductId.push({ ProductId: $(this).val() });
    });
    var things = JSON.stringify({ UpdateProductStatus: allSelectedProductId });

    $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Products/UpdateProductStatus',
        data: things,
        success: function () {
            ....
    });
});
```